# Calling a different variable depending of the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var mods1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var mods2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
var mods3 = ['js', 'hates', 'me', ':('];


jQuery('div').append('<ul class="modlist"></ul>');
jQuery.each(mods1, function(i) {
    jQuery('<li/>').html(mods1[i]).appendTo('.modlist');
});
```

I need to use a different variable (mods1, modsN,...) depending of the URL where this script is used.

The URLs always have the same structure:

http://www.example.com/NUMBER/ 
http://www.example.com/NUMBER/example/ 
http://www.example.com/NUMBER/example/example

The "number" part is the one I can use to differentiate between pages.

jsFiddle with my example code running: http://jsfiddle.net/RZHxz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var url = "/1/example"; // location.pathname
var id = url.split("/")[1];

mods = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    ['js', 'hates', 'me', ':(']
];

jQuery('div').append('<ul class="modlist"></ul>');
jQuery.each(mods[id], function(i,v) {
    jQuery('<li/>').html(v).appendTo('.modlist');
});
```

I've made the `mods` into an array as that's how you're effectively accessing them anyway, also, the `each()` function passes the value to the handling function as a parameter, so you don't need to go off to the array again.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RZHxz/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Just parse the [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location):

```
var url = location.pathname.substr(1),
    arr_url = url.split('/'),
    NUM = arr_url[0];
```

Or, if you like your code more compact:

```
var NUM = location.pathname.substr(1).split('/')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that all *mods* variables are within common `mods` object and `mods1` is used by default:

```
var mods = {
    mods1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    mods2: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    mods3: ['js', 'hates', 'me', ':(']
};

var key = "mods" + (/^\/(\d+)/.exec(location.pathname) || [,1])[1];
$.each(mods[key], function(i) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: If the regex doesn't find a match this'll result in a typeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem You're right, mistaken a bit. Now should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the number will be there, you could get it easily like so:

```
var urlNumber = parseInt(location.pathname.substr(1),10); // always use a radix
//or, if the number needn't be there
var urlNumber = (location.pathname.match(/^\/([0-9]+)\//) || ['no','number'])[1];
```

The second returns the number if it was in the url, or `number` if it wasn't